# crystal reports forces visual studio to restart when connecting to database

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports, restart

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Pro with Crystal Reports version 13.0.20.2399.  I attempted to change the database location (right click Database Fields, choose Set Datasource Location).  It let me do that, but now when I attempt to preview the report, the Enter Fields box displays as a blank box, and then Visual Studio restarts without a distinct error message.  I have changed the connection back to the old database, and this error still continues.

Comment: Did  you look for an error message in the windows event log? It is a long shot, but it is costless to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped having the failure when I granted View Definition on my stored procedure to my user.  Previously, I had just had execute permission.

Oddly, my original development was done in this fashion, but when I wnt back some months later, I had this problem.  It may be a newer version of Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

What DB Server/client are you using?

Try upgrading to SP 20 from here:

[Download Link](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads)

Use DebugDiag and capture the dump file on devenv.exe and see if it captures anything. Could be a permission issue on a dependency or something similar.

Try starting VS by right clicking on the devenv.exe and selecting Run as Administrator.

Hidayatullah